# Download pdf files from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download a pdf file from Firebase storage but it does not work. following the code:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {          
        File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file_name");
        if(!rootPath.exists()) {
            rootPath.mkdirs();
        }
        final File file = new File(rootPath,  lista.get(position).getNome()+".pdf");
        storageRef.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        });
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}});
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
E/FileDownloadTask: Exception occurred during file write.  Aborting.
       java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
           at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
           at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
           at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1000)
           at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.zza(Unknown Source:75)
           at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source:190)
           at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source:2)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
            An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
             Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
```

I set these as required permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be in the `storageReference`. Try to follow the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?hl=es-419)